# Kendo Datepicker month content, how to call a function

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

Within the content property of the Kendo date picker, I would like to call a controller function to set the background colour of a given day cell within the calendar. My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.7.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css">
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <input kendo-date-picker k-options="datePickerOptions"/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module("MyModule", ["kendo.directives"])
        .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.datePickerOptions = {
                value: new Date(),
                        month: {
                            content: (data) => {{dateBackground(data)}}
                    },
            };
      
      
             $scope.dateBackground = function(data) {
             return "<span class='color'>" + data.value + "</span>";
           }
        })
</script>

<style>
  .k-calendar-td:has(.color){
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

However when I try this code I get this error:

`result:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: dateBackground is not defined at content (result:7:36) at _e (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at content (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at ee (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at Object.content (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at init.navigate (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at init.setOptions (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at N._setOptions (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at N._calendar (kendo.all.js:322401:19) at N.open (kendo.all.js:322401:19)`

Can I do this? If so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `$scope.dateBackground(data)` since its defined on the scope of the controller!

```js
angular.module("MyModule", ["kendo.directives"])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.datePickerOptions = {
      value: new Date(),
      month: {
        content: (data) => {
          {
            $scope.dateBackground(data)
          }
        }
      },
    };


    $scope.dateBackground = function(data) {
      return "<span class='color'>" + data.value + "</span>";
    }
  })
```

```css
.k-calendar-td:has(.color) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>AngularJS example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.7.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css">
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.2.829/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example" ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input kendo-date-picker k-options="datePickerOptions" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I attempted to use your code as is but I see in each cell the text:

(data) => {{ $scope.dateBackground(data) }}

Like it was taking the string from the content field and using that as part of the HTML output. I did try string Interpolation, but I just get angular errors with that.